# Spring Security Oauth2. Store refresh_token on server side

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

There is `spring-security-oauth2 service` with `grant_type=password, refresh token`.

I want to store `refresh_token` in java code and not send it to client via http(s). (why? - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507051/oauth2-refresh-token-how-to-store-it-on-client-side))

*So, 2 cases have to be handled:*
 1. do not send `refresh_token` in `response`
 2. automatically insert `refresh_token` in `request` when in needed

1st can be done as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072081/change-response-in-oauth2-spring)

**Question**: how 2nd case can be done?

Usually, to get access token via `refresh_token` following request have to be sent:

```
POST: .../oaut/token?refresh_token=***&grant_type=refresh_token
```

I want to send

```
POST: .../oaut/token?access_token=***&grant_type=refresh_token
```

and then fetch `refresh_token` corresponding to `access_token` from some storage and add it as request parameter

Answer (score 0):

Simple custom Spring Filter can help here. In particular OncePerRequestFilter.class [[example]](http://srlawr.blogspot.com.by/2011/09/creating-custom-filter-in-spring.html)